# Deserializing an Enum with borsh

Tags: borsh, decode

How do I make a "kind": "enum" using borsh?

In the IDL, it says that it's an enum instead of "struct".

Here is what I tried:

```
const WhitelistMode = borsh.rustEnum([
    borsh.struct([
        borsh.u32('mintsPerUser'),
        borsh.array(borsh.u8(), 32, 'merkleRoot')
    ], "WalletBased"),
    borsh.struct([
        borsh.publicKey('tokenMint'),
        borsh.bool('burn')
    ], "TokenBased"),
    borsh.struct([
        borsh.option(borsh.u32(), 'mintsPerUser')
    ], "Public"),
    borsh.struct([
        borsh.publicKey('verifiedCreator'),
        borsh.u32('mintsPerNft')
    ], "NFTBased")
], undefined, borsh.u32())

const SaleFaze = borsh.struct([
    borsh.i64('start'),
    borsh.u64('price'),
    borsh.option(borsh.publicKey(), 'currency'),
    WhitelistMode,
    borsh.str('name')
]);
```

I've tried a bunch of variations, none of them seem to work for me, I always get either:

Error: fields cannot contain unnamed variable-length layout

or

TypeError: defaultLayout must be null or a Layout

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what version of Borsh-JS you're using, but there's probably a way to "tag" the enum name. In the most recent version, that would look like:

```
const WhitelistMode = borsh.rustEnum([
    { WalletBased: borsh.struct([
        borsh.u32('mintsPerUser'),
        borsh.array(borsh.u8(), 32, 'merkleRoot')
    ], "WalletBased") },
    { TokenBased: borsh.struct([
        borsh.publicKey('tokenMint'),
        borsh.bool('burn')
    ], "TokenBased") },
    { Public: borsh.struct([
        borsh.option(borsh.u32(), 'mintsPerUser')
    ], "Public") },
    { NFTBased: borsh.struct([
        borsh.publicKey('verifiedCreator'),
        borsh.u32('mintsPerNft')
    ], "NFTBased") }
], undefined, borsh.u32())
```